# about websocket rfc6455 dataframing and how to send or get message between websocket server and client

Tags: html, websocket

'\x00hello\xff'

//from what I know, previous message translate of websocket looks like above

hello guys,
now I'm studying to make C language websocket server and done handshake
//I did check if onopen is working or not

but I face new trouble again!
previous version of rfc6455 looks just need to add '\x00' and '\xff' with 
sentence that I wanna send to client, but now rfc6455 looks more difficult!!!
so is there no way to send sentence more easily alike previous version or should I
make dataframe? //I just wanna make chat program T_T dont need binary or other things...!

thank you for reading my question!!
//p.s : here looks so good! really thank you for kind and helpful answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous format you mention is normally referred to as [Hixie-76](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76).  You could use this in the short term if you limit yourself to testing against Safari (on both dektop & iOS).  (Note that this will only be a short term solution as Safari will be updated in future to use a later, incompatible, protocol version.)

If you want to work against other browsers (e.g. Chrome, Firefox) then you'll need to implement the data framing describe in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).  There is no way to communicate with these browsers without implementing this data framing.

Comment: teanks to teach me again : ) but could you let me know one again? now I'm wondering if I should convert letters from utf-8 to ASCII code to look in server side!

Comment: Yes, text messages are utf-8 encoded.  BTW, if answers to this or other questions are useful to you can you consider upvoting and/or accepting them?  You do this using the up arrow beside each answer and by clicking on the outline of a tick beside the most helpful answer.

Comment: sorry I'm new about stack overflow so didn't know : ) but for going number up maybe I need reputation? I will answer to questions of others in my knowledge! anyway, again thanks simonc!!!

Comment: @nathan I think you were clicking on the wrong arrow.  The one above the number, pointing up, is used to recognise a useful answer.  Anyone can use this.  The one below the number, pointing down, is used to say that an answer is poor/unhelpful.  You need a higher reputation to use that one.